# Change color of searched text in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to change the text colour and background whenever i search for a particular text.
Example in a string of "this is a good boy", if i search for boy, i want boy to be highlighted in the string.

My reducer file

````
        return {
            ...state,
            filtered: state.dispatches.filter(dispatch => {
                const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, 'gi');
                return dispatch.title.match(regex) || dispatch.body.match(regex);
            })
        } ```

My Component
``` <td onClick={() => setCurrent(dispatch)}><Link to="/orders"  className={`link-style ${title.includes(`${message}`) ? 'activeText' : ''}`}>{title}</Link></td> ```

The css
``` .activeText {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #e5077f !important;
} ```

The component i am rendering
````

```
// Display Filtered Dispatches 
const displayFilteredDispatch = filtered && filtered.slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + dispatchesPerPage)
                                .map(filtered => (
                                <DispatchItem  dispatch={filtered} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={filtered} message={message} key={filtered.id}/>
                                ))
```

```
The problem above is that it highlights everything instead of the searched text
```

Comment: can you add a codesadbox?

Comment: Okay..give me a moment.. Let me sign up

Comment: On a second thought, to add the full code is going to take a lot of time.
Maybe you could illustrate with a test example

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of highlighting the searched text. I'm not able to put together the demo inside stackoverflow so here is the link to the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rrgkw8?file=index.tsx)

Same code here:

```
// imports
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-highlight-words@0.17.0/dist/main.min.js"></script>
```

React Component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const HINT = 'Search any name';

  const searchName = async text => {
    const URI = `https://api.nationalize.io/?name=${text}`;
    return fetch(URI);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!text) {
        setData(HINT);
        return;
      }

      const res = await searchName(text);
      const data = await res.text();
      setData(data);
    })();
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={text} onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <br />

      <Highlighter searchWords={[text]} textToHighlight={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: My follow up question is that do i replace the component i am rendering with this Highlighter??
 // Display Filtered Dispatches 
    const displayFilteredDispatch = filtered && filtered.slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + dispatchesPerPage)
                                .map(filtered => (
                                    <DispatchItem  dispatch={filtered} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={filtered} message={message} key={filtered.id}/>
                                    ))
That is the filtered component i am rendering, which is an object i displayed in a table..How do i then use highlighter

Comment: I edited my question to show the component..Thank you

Comment: @nkemjikaobi I think you figured it out. If that's the case consider upvoting my accepting my solution.

Comment: Hey @nkemjikaobi it's been a while. Let me know if you got everything you need. I'm glad if I could help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

This will highlight only the matched text.

```
const splitMatchedText = (str)=> {
  const regExp = new RegExp(str, 'gi');
  return title.replace(regExp, (match) => `<span style="color: white;background-color: #e5077f">${match}</span>}`);
}


<td onClick={() => setCurrent(dispatch)}>
  <Link to="/orders" className="link-style" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={splitMatchedText('boy')}></Link>
</td>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: the problem now is that , where do i put this function you specified?...The above code i wrote, that was my reducer file..so when there is a match, it returns all the matched objects to the state(called filtered)...I am then mapping whatever is in that state in my component